# Adding multiple rows to newly created columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using pandas to store the results of a machine learning model, and I have a dataframe that stores the input data. I want to extend that dataframe with the two outputs that the model returns, but I don't know how to do it.

I've tried doing somethin like this:

```py
import pandas
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'col2':[1,2,3,4,5]})
df[['col3', 'col4']] = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

But it throws an error

```py
Exception has occurred: ValueError
Columns must be same length as key
  File "D:\InSilicoOP-FUAM\In Silico OP\src\pruebas.py", line 20, in <module>
    df[['col3', 'col4']] = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

I've also tried with
`df['col3', 'col4'] = [1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]` and `df['col3', 'col4'] = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]` and those throw `ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (5)`

I know I can assign each column separatedly, like so

```py
df['col3'] = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

But then I'd have to separate the results from the model (which is a big problem on it's own...)

Is there a way to assign multiple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpack the values from the results list and assign them to the columns `col3` and `col4`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'col2':[1,2,3,4,5]})

results = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]

df['col3'], df['col4'] = results
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your results are stored in a `list` of lists, you could convert that to  `pandas` DataFrame and `join` to the original:

```
results = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]

>>> df.join(pd.DataFrame(results, index=["col_3","col_4"]).T)

   col1  col2  col_3  col_4
0     1     1      1      1
1     2     2      2      2
2     3     3      3      3
3     4     4      4      4
4     5     5      5      5
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example you could use the loc property. Make sure you insert the array in the right shape though:

```
df.loc[:,["col3", "col4"]] = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]]
```

Alternatively you can use numpy's transpose to create the right shape from the array that you had in your example.

```
df.loc[:,["col3", "col4"]] = np.transpose([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write the outputs of col3 and col4 to another dataframe and then join them. I'm not sure if this is still separating your results out from the model?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'col2':[1,2,3,4,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col3':[1,2,3,4,5],'col4':[1,2,3,4,5]})
df3 = df.join(df2)
print(df3)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     1     1     1
1     2     2     2     2
2     3     3     3     3
3     4     4     4     4
4     5     5     5     5
```